# ARKit app cannot replay a recorded ARSession from Reality Composer

Tags: arkit, realitykit, replay, reality-composer

I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/recording_and_replaying_ar_session_data) to record an ARKit mov session using the Reality Composer app, but when I load in Xcode and run with an ARKit app, the app shows a black screen and shows errors:
The app runs fine without the .mov file

```
2021-07-17 20:57:40.773522-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:40.773645-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] MOVReaderInterface - ERROR - Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'.}
2021-07-17 20:57:41.614815-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'mdta/com.apple.arkit.arimagedata'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.615833-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'mdta/com.apple.arkit.arimagedata'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.615940-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'com.apple.reality.kind.data.accelerometer'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.615988-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'com.apple.reality.kind.data.gyroscope'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.616028-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'Motion'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.616069-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'Location'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.616110-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVACameraCalibration'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.616155-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] MOVReaderInterface - ERROR - Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVACameraCalibration'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVACameraCalibration'.}
2021-07-17 20:57:41.618048-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CMData'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.618116-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] MOVReaderInterface - ERROR - Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CMData'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CMData'.}
2021-07-17 20:57:41.618151-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.618185-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322420] MOVReaderInterface - ERROR - Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'.}
2021-07-17 20:57:41.642976-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'mdta/com.apple.arkit.arimagedata'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.643786-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'com.apple.reality.kind.data.accelerometer'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.643898-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'com.apple.reality.kind.data.gyroscope'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.643933-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'Motion'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.643973-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'Location'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.644019-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVACameraCalibration'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
2021-07-17 20:57:41.644137-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] MOVReaderInterface - ERROR - Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVACameraCalibration'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CVACameraCalibration'.}
2021-07-17 20:57:41.654159-0700 ARKitInteraction[10346:6322385] ⚠️⚠️⚠️ WARNING [MOVStreamReader]: Cannot grab metadata. Unknwon metadata stream 'CMData'. ⚠️⚠️⚠️
```

Comment: have you found any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in Xcode 12 there was a Build's issue when activating a replay feature for recorded HEVC files with Reality Composer's session metadata. Now, in Xcode 13.2, all issues are gone - everything works fine and there's no black screen.

---

[image]

---

The only problem, however, is the extremely slow decryption of metadata from recorded AR Session. It took almost 7 minutes to upload and apply a 40-sec video's metadata (ARWorldMap, planes, anchors, etc) into Xcode project.

[image]

P.S.

I recorded a session in iOS 15.2, in Reality Composer 1.5.2 on iPhone X.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Xcode 14.2 14C18 ```⛔️⛔️⛔️ ERROR [MOVReaderInterface]: Error Domain=com.apple.AppleCV3DMOVKit.readererror Code=9 "CVAUserEvent: Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'."```